# A question about Linked List

Tags: java, generics

Im copying an array of objects to the linked list  from a student class that i already made, but in the 5th line , the following error is showing : (" cannot find symbol - class E ")

Why is that?

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentLinkedList
{

    private List<E[]> studentLL = new LinkedList<E[]>();


    public StudentLinkedList(Student[] st)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < st.length; i++)
        {
            studentLL.add(st[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: we couldn't find that symbol either...

Comment: What is E supposed to be?  Is it a generic, or a class you have already defined?

Comment: @WM: Do you really want a List that contains Arrays that contain Students?

Comment: @Jason : yea im trying to do that but im not that familiar with the concept...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably wanted to write:

```
private List<Student> studentLL = new LinkedList<Student>();
```

instead.

When declaring such a field, you specify the type of the elements of a list. The type you have specified is `E`, but the compiler doesn't know anything called that.

Comment: yea this worked but now the method add(st[i]);  is the problem.. should i cast it.. ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the LinkedList instanciator to `private List<Student> studentLL= new LinkedList<Student>();`

Comment: yea this worked but now the method add(st[i]); is the problem.. should i cast it.. ?